# Suspending main process in C#

Tags: c#, process

I am developing an application in C#.  As part of an error condition, I would like to bring up a file in Notepad for the user to edit (while pausing the main process).  I am able to bring the file up using Process.Start.  What I can't figure out is how to pause the main application until the user saves or quits out of the notepad file.  Is there something other than Process.start that I could use that would launch the Notepad.exe in the main process or some other trick I can use.  I feel like there is an easy solution to it that I am overlooking.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [Process.WaitForExit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8.aspx) to block the main program until Notepad is closed.

Making it block until the file is *saved or closed* would be a bit trickier.

One option here would be to have a ManualResetEvent, and wait on it.  You could then listen for [Process.Exited](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited.aspx) (after setting [Process.EnableRaisingEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.enableraisingevents.aspx)), and use this to call Set() on the wait handle.  This would handle allowing your code to continue when the process exits.

For handling the file being saved, a separate [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) could watch for the save (file change) on the file itself.  If the file saves/changes, you could continue on by calling Set().

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be able to do something like this.

```
var notePad = new Process { StartInfo = { FileName = "notepad.exe", Arguments = "newfile.txt" } };
        notePad.Start();

        while(!notePad.HasExited)
        {

        }

        MessageBox.Show("Done.");
```

The "Done." message box shouldn't show up until you close notepad. Then again, the answer above mine is less hackish.

Comment: Better to use `notePad.WaitForExit()`, as you won't eat 100% of a CPU core waiting in a spin like this ;)

Comment: Yea, I must admit spinning in a while loop isn't the most elegant of solutions, haha. Thanks for the tip.